# Perl regex issue with multiple line matching

Tags: regex, perl

My goal is to extract a part of a big string on multiple lines (this string is A).
The substring extracted (call it B) will have a new string added to it, the new substring is C.
Finally in A, I will replace B by C.

Here is my code with some explanations...my substring B looks like this :

```
$B = 'define category "Allowed"\n\twww.toto.com\n\twww.tata.com\n\t{...}\nend category "Allowed
```

It's a list of websites. (in real, the string is bigger - hundreds of websites inside)
It starts with `define category "Allowed"` and finishes with `end category "Allowed"`.
Websites are separated by "\n\t".

I want all URLs so I do this

```
if ( $A =~ m/define category "Allowed"\n\t(.*)\nend category "Allowed"/s) {
    my $list = $1 ;
```

Then I put my list in an ARRAY

```
    my @items = split /\n\t/, $list ;
```

Then I add my new website "www.titi.com"

```
   push @items, "www.titi.com" ;
```

Then I create a new list

```
    my $new_list = join "\n\t", @items;
```

And finally, I replace the old list by the new one

```
   $A =~ s/$list/$new_list/;
}
```

The issue is that $A is not modified (new website is not added).

For information, I work with arrays because this function add a new website, but I will need to be able to remove websites from the list too, so it's easier (for me) to work with arrays instead of working on the string directly.

I made some investigations, and I found that when I extract "$list" and then verify it matches with $A, the result is negative :

```
if ( $A =~ m/$list/s ) { print "MATCH\n" ; }
```

...it never prints "MATCH"...What am I missing ?

Since $list is extracted from a pattern matching, it must match with the original string, no ?

I found an alternative but it's dirty :
I only replace the last website by last website AND new website like this :

```
$A =~ s/$items[$#items-1]/$items[$#items-1]\n\t$items[$#items]/;
```

This works but it doesn't satisfy me.

Answer (score 0):

> The issue is that $A is not modified...

I tried the code and it modified `$A` correctly. I tried with the following `$A` and `$B`:

```
my $B = 'define category "Allowed"' 
    . "\n\twww.toto.com\n\twww.tata.com\n\t{...}\nend category "
    . '"Allowed"';
my $A = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx' . $B . 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy';
```

Please show more of your code.

Comment: I uploaded all my code. The only difference is that the string is bigger. An other test I did is : print $A in file, print $list in an other file. Then I deleted in $A all things that didn't match (i.e all stuff before and after $list). I launched a "diff" command on those files and there is no difference...

Comment: Ok, could you upload the smallest string `$A` that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't because is it related to my work. But if you think my code is good, there must be something tricky in the $A string. I will work on it to find what's goin' on (special char issue ? I saw that I have somes "%20" in websites for example)

Comment: @StephaneProud Thanks, I will have a look at it later today. You could also email me the example (you find my email in my profile).

Comment: I Found it. the following website is the problem www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/compiler-dependencies.html. When it's in $A, it's well extracted in $list (a print confirms it) but if I if try `( $A =~ m/$list/s ) { print "MATCH\n" ; }` it never prints MATCH. When I remove the website from $A, it's OK. the "+" character is the issue, how can I get rid off

Comment: I'm stupid, I tried it before, but added some extra quote around my $list, so even with quotemeta it didn't match...